# Colorize yAxis labels and chart lines in HighchartTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I started using HighchartTable and while trying to customize the colors and styles I can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the yAxis (left) labels or the guide lines that run through the graph. Here is what I have so far...

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('table.highchart').bind('highchartTable.beforeRender', function(event, highChartConfig) 
    {
        highChartConfig.chart.backgroundColor = '#191919';
        highChartConfig.chart.borderWidth = '1';
        highChartConfig.chart.borderColor = '#000000';
        highChartConfig.chart.borderRadius = '8';
        highChartConfig.chart.style = { "fontFamily": "Arial" };
        highChartConfig.title.style = { "color": "#CCCCCC" };
        highChartConfig.tooltip.style = { "color": "#000000" };
        highChartConfig.tooltip.backgroundColor = '#CCCCCC';
        highChartConfig.tooltip.borderWidth = '1';
        highChartConfig.tooltip.borderColor = '#000000';
        highChartConfig.tooltip.borderRadius = '8';
        highChartConfig.xAxis.labels.style = { "color": "#CCCCCC" };
    }).highchartTable();
});
```

Here is current JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Manvaril/cx1x1qpj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the style for each `yAxis`, since there may exist [multiple](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) of them:

```
for (var i = 0; i < highChartConfig.yAxis.length; i++) {
    highChartConfig.yAxis[i].labels.style = { "color": "#CCCCCC" };
}
```

[See working fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/cx1x1qpj/1/)